# ROS packpages scheduled date for Ubuntu 12.10 (Quantal)

Tags: ubuntu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there any scheduled date for realeasing the packpages for the new Ubuntu version?

Compiling from source can be painful with some stacks/nodes such as rviz.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/46446/ros-packpages-scheduled-date-for-ubuntu-12.10-(quantal)/) by [Victor_ocv2](https://answers.ros.org/users/3431/victor_ocv2/) on ROS Answers with karma: 483 on 2012-10-22

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Victor_ocv2](https://answers.ros.org/users/3431/victor_ocv2/) on 2012-10-22**:
I have came across the following repository while searching into other questions:
http://packages.ros.org/ros-shadow-fixed

It has many packpages for quantal but I am not sure what means to use this repo and not the official one

**Comment by [Victor_ocv2](https://answers.ros.org/users/3431/victor_ocv2/) on 2012-10-22**:
I have installed ros-groovy using that repository but it does not have the ros-groovy-visualization stack nor the ros-groovy-slam-gmapping stack which I need.

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2012-10-25**:
Groovy is still in development, not yet released. Those stacks are probably not available yet. Or, they may disappear while rebuilding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ROS Groovy Galapagos will support Ubuntu Quantal. Its currently-scheduled release date is 2012-11-15.

Fuerte will not officially support Quantal.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2012-10-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Grega Pusnik](https://answers.ros.org/users/1849/grega-pusnik/) on 2012-11-15**:
Do you have any info if Groovy is beeing released today or will it be postponed? Maybe beta release?

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2012-11-15**:
Here's the latest: http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.science.robotics.ros.user/17023